# jqGrid and the autowidth option. How does it work?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using jqGrid with the `autowidth` option set to `true`.

According to the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options):

> When set to true, the grid width is recalculated automatically to the width of the parent element. This is done only initially when the grid is created. In order to resize the grid when the parent element changes width you should apply custom code and use a setGridWidth method for this purpose

This makes the grid occupy all the width available in the parent element. 
Another effect of this property is that every column shrinks to fit the width available.

This works very well. However, I have one page where don't want the columns to shrink to fit the grid width, but they should occupy the space that I set within the `colModel` for them.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean on the grid table element?

Comment: Found the solution: I did not realized that the shrinkToFit option had a default value of true. I have set it to false and everything is ok now...

Comment: No, I meant on the grid.

Comment: Ok! anyway I have found the solution. As I wrote in the previous comment I left the autowidth option set to true and I have set the shrinkToFit option to false. thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Solution: `shrinkToFit: false`

Comment: How can do it vs Subgrid?

Answer (score 12):

set

> autowidth=true,
>   shrinkToFit=false

this setting will make **width of jqgrid  frame** equal the parent ( usually equal the width of browser ) ; and **column width** equal the width defined in colModel ;
unfornatelly jqgrid 4.3 donot give an simple way by setting a property  to auto fit/resize the **column width** basing on width  of the content ( text in cell );

***default in jqgrid :***

> autowidth=false,
>   shrinkToFit=true

please see the three properties of options of jqgrid  in [jqgrid option wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions);

> autowidth
>
> shrinkToFit
>
> width

and property of colModel in [jqgrid colModel wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options)

> width
>
> fixed

I think the priority for jqgrid frame width is **jqgrid frame autowidth > jqgrid frame width > sum of column width **

the priority for column width  is **colmodel fixed > jqgrid frame shrinkToFit > colmodel** width

Comment: autowidth: true, shrinkToFit: false!
colon ' `:` ' sign instead of equals ' `=` ' sign