# Get row data on custom button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using free jqgrid 4.14 and I need to have a custom image (some kind of mail icon) in my grid and when the image is clicked it should open a modal window having a form and which has the data of clicked row in the message field of form and also has other couple of field like sender mail id, receiver mail id and also a subject.

So, I was able to have a custom image in my grid. Now, we have **onSelectRow** property by which we can get the id of the clicked row and we have **getRowData** which will give the data of the columns.

So, I made changed onSelectRow a bit like this

```
onSelectRow: function(id){ 
            if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
                jQuery(this).restoreRow(lastSel); 
                lastSel=id; 
                var rowId = $(this).getRowData(lastSel);
            } 
            jQuery(this).editRow(id, true); 
        }
```

Now, this will give the data of each row when it is clicked. But how will I get same functionality when my custom image is clicked?

EDIT: I need something like this-

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Admin3.htm

But here I am not able to find the image like here it finding

Comment: Please create a minimal example in snippet, if you can.

Comment: @Iceman please check now

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement the requirement. One from the easiest one I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42222717/315935). You can add the column with `formatter: "actions"`

```
{
    name: "act", template: "actions", width: 25,
    formatoptions: { editbutton: false, delbutton: false }
}
```

and the jqGrid option, which specify additional custom buttons

```
actionsNavOptions: {
    mailicon: "fa-envelope-o",
    custom: [
        {
            action: "mail",
            position: "first",
            onClick: function (options) {
                alert("Mail for rowid=" + options.rowid);
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/3tuxg71z/

Comment: thanks for the response I tried your solution there were two basic problem the column which I have to apply this mail icon should not be in all rows only selected rows how I can do that also the alert is only coming when we click twice...can we do alert in one click only?

Comment: one more thing for mef a-envelope-o image is not coming also whatever custom image it is not taking instead it is coming like a up arrow icon

Comment: @shv22: Test my demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/3tuxg71z/. The alert come on **every** click on the mail icon. Please reread the text of your your question. Do you wrote something about `multiselect: true`? Next: I created the demo for you. If you have some problem, which you can't solve yourself you should modify my demo till the place where you have problem. I have to do my main job and try to help other on the stackoverflow in pauses in my main job or in my free time. Think about saving my time too and do maximal what you can do yourself.

Comment: thanks for your help...actually I used onSelectRow as well as onCellSelect to check whether it is that particular column where I have to mail and with help of onSelectRow I get the values of that particular row.

Comment: @shv22: Could you modify the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/3tuxg71z/ so that it demonstrates the problem, which you have?

Comment: @shv22: If you need to place image in multiple elements then one use typically any inline element, like `<span>` or `<i>` with the class having `background-image`. Usage of `<img>` for multiple elements is bad. I started my answer with "There are many ways to implement the requirement". The best way depends on your exact requirements and from *your existing code*. You don't posted any code or a demo and posted the reference to my old demo, which uses `formatter: "actions"`. Because of that I posted my answer, which uses `formatter: "actions"`. Please create demos which demonstrates what you do

Comment: I will try to create one but as in comments I told you I don't know in your demo how to show the img icon to only selected rows...in my code I am using a custom formatter to display to selected rows only...thats why I commented...