# jqGrid get row data on custom button click

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have following custom grid

[image: grid screenshot]

I need to get `rowObject` when user clicks the image in Serial column to show a dialog allowing user to select another serial from available list for that row and then send the selected serial back to server.

As the images on column 5 and 6 execute functions related to data in their column, I cannot combine all images to a single action column with edit and delete buttons thus [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520014) is not suitable for me.

Currently I'm using following method to find desired row and call my function with row data. This method is slow as it has to go through data in a for loop and find the matching record. I stripped out all unrelated code and here is the rest

```
    var TerminalColNames = [
        'id',
        'Serial'
    ];

    var TerminalColModel = [
        { name: 'id', width: '180px', formatter: TerminalID_Formatter},
        { name: 'serial', width: '160px', formatter: Formatter, sortable: false }
    ];

    function TerminalID_Formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return ' ' +
            '<img src="pencil.png" onclick="return edit(\'' + cellvalue + '\')"> ' +
            '<img src="bin.png"    onclick="return delete(\'' + cellvalue + '\')"> ' +
            cellvalue;
    }

    function Formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<img src="link.png" onclick="return bind(\'' + rowObject.id + '\')"></a> ' + rowObject.serial.current;
    }

    function CreateGrid(TableElement, colNames, colModel, data) {

        $(TableElement).jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: data,
            colNames: colNames,
            colModel: colModel,
            height: '150px',
            //onSelectRow: function (id, status, e) {
            //    rowData = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", id);
            //    return RowAction(rowData);
            //}
        });
    }

    $(function () {
        CreateGrid('#TerminalGrid', TerminalColNames, TerminalColModel, data.terminals);
    });

    function RowAction(rowData) {
        alert('Row Action:' + JSON.stringify(rowData));
    }

    function bind(id) {
        for (i in data.terminals){
            if (data.terminals[i].id == id){
                return ProcessBind(data.terminals[i]);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    function ProcessBind(rowObject){
        if (rowObject.id)
            alert('Bind:' + rowObject.serial.avail.length);
        else 
            alert('Bind not found');
        return true;
    }

    var data = {
        "id": "1234",
        "terminals": [
            {
                "id": "111111",
                "serial": {
                    "current": "888888",
                    "avail": [
                        "444444",
                        "555555",
                        "666666"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "777777",
                "serial": {
                    "current": "333333",
                    "avail": [
                        "999999",
                        "000000",
                    ]
                }
            },
            //.....
        ]
        //.....
    }
```

I didn't use `$(this).closest('tr').attr('id')` because I believe it is much slower as it has to go through DOM to find the id and then go through the JSON data to find the row data. It also needs `key: true` to be set in id column.

**Question**

Is there a better method to get the record data?
Or is there a jqGrid method to return rowIndex in JSON array?

**EDIT**
I forget to mention that I'm using [oleg's free jqgrid 4.15.2](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? The statements like `$(this).closest('tr').attr('id')` works **very quickly**. Every DOM element has `parentElement` property. `$(this).closest('tr')` just use `parentElement` property in the loop and test and use `nodeName` property to test for `"TR"`. `.attr('id')` uses mostly `.getAttribute` method and is very quickly too.

Comment: On the other side the usage `onclick` generate *separate* Function object for every element. `onClick` function used in https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520014 is only one. I posted additionally many answers where I used *one* `beforeSelectRow` callback where `e.target` was analysed to detect, which image/button from which column was clicked. It allows to have *one* `beforeSelectRow` callback, which handle *all* clicks on all images/buttons. If you need I can post references to such old answers. Additionally multiple `<img>` work mostly slowly as multiple `<span>` or `<div>` with background image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd recommended you to make some minor fixes in your code:

- change the properties `width: '180px'` to `width: 180` and the option `height: '150px'` to `height: 150`. The current code works, but it's misunderstandable because `width: '180em'` will be interpreted as `width: 180` (or `180px`), but `height: '150em'` will really increase the height of the grid.
- one should reduce the number of **global** functions in JavaScript code. If `CreateGrid` function for example be used only once inside of `$(function () {...});` and `var data` only inside of `CreateGrid` then you should move the declaration of variables/functions inside of the corresponding scope.

Now about your main question. Event parameter of `beforeSelectRow`, `onSelectRow` or `onCellSelect` callbacks provides all information, which you need. `target` property is the DOM element clicked inside of the grid. One can test its `class`, `tagName`, `name` or other properties to verify that specific image/icon is clicked. One don't need to use `onclick` attribute.

About the performance. It's important to understand that access of properties of DOM element (`class`, `tagName`, `name`, `parentElement` and so on) is very quickly. The time to access of the properties isn't depend on the *total number of elements on the page*. It makes the working of `closest`, `hasClass` and other functions very quickly. It's recommended way. The below code provides an example of accessing to the full row data:

```
onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
    var $self = $(this), $target = $(e.target),
        p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        rowData = $self.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid),
        $td = $target.closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
        iCol = $td.length > 0 ? $td[0].cellIndex : -1,
        cmName = iCol >= 0 ? p.colModel[iCol].name : "";

    switch (cmName) {
        case "id":
            if ($target.hasClass("myedit")) {
                alert("edit icon is clicked in the row with rowid=" + rowid);
            } else if ($target.hasClass("mydelete")) {
                alert("delete icon is clicked in the row with rowid=" + rowid);
            }
            break;
        case "serial":
            if ($target.hasClass("mylink")) {
                alert("link icon is clicked in the row with rowid=" + rowid);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
                  }
    alert("full row data:\n\n" + JSON.stringify(rowData));
    //    return RowAction(rowData);
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dfra7snb/

**Code snippet:**

```js
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    function CreateGrid(TableElement, colNames, colModel, data) {
        $(TableElement).jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: data,
            colNames: colNames,
            colModel: colModel,
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
                var $self = $(this), $target = $(e.target),
                    p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
                    rowData = $self.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid),
                    $td = $target.closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
                    iCol = $td.length > 0 ? $td[0].cellIndex : -1,
                    cmName = iCol >= 0 ? p.colModel[iCol].name : "";

                switch (cmName) {
                    case "id":
                        if ($target.hasClass("myedit")) {
                            alert("edit icon is clicked in the row with rowid=" + rowid);
                        } else if ($target.hasClass("mydelete")) {
                            alert("delete icon is clicked in the row with rowid=" + rowid);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "serial":
                        if ($target.hasClass("mylink")) {
                            alert("link icon is clicked in the row with rowid=" + rowid);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                              }
                alert("full row data:\n\n" + JSON.stringify(rowData));
                //    return RowAction(rowData);
            },
            height: 150
        });
    }
    var TerminalColNames = [
        'id',
        'Serial'
    ];

    function TerminalID_Formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<span class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg myedit" aria-hidden="true"></span>' +
            '<span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg mydelete" aria-hidden="true"></span>' +
            cellvalue;
    }

    function Formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<span class="fa fa-link fa-rotate-90 fa-lg mylink" aria-hidden="true"></span>' +
            rowObject.serial.current;
    }
    var TerminalColModel = [
        { name: 'id', width: '180em', formatter: TerminalID_Formatter},
        { name: 'serial', width: 160, formatter: Formatter, sortable: false }
    ];
    var data = {
        "id": "1234",
        "terminals": [
            {
                "id": "111111",
                "serial": {
                    "current": "888888",
                    "avail": [
                        "444444",
                        "555555",
                        "666666"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "777777",
                "serial": {
                    "current": "333333",
                    "avail": [
                        "999999",
                        "000000",
                    ]
                }
            },
            //.....
        ]
        //.....
    };
    CreateGrid('#TerminalGrid', TerminalColNames, TerminalColModel, data.terminals);
});
```

```css
.myedit, .mydelete, .mylink {
    margin: 0 0.25em;
}
.myedit {
    color: green;
}
.mydelete {
    color: red;
}
.mylink {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.2/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.2/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>

<table id="TerminalGrid"></table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I was looking at the answers in jqGrid tag and there are about 1900 of them. finding the answer you mentioned wasn't as easy as I thought. I used `beforeSelectRow` instead of `onSelectRow` rest of the code is similar. However on the matter of global functions, you are right, however I stripped the code for this question. Formatter function is about 170 lines and if I put 3 of them in the `colModel` I'm going to have a hardtime reading it later. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct you can use the method **getLocalRow( rowid )** in case you use the local data. This method return quick the rowdata by index when the rowid is know.

Another trick is to use the internal _index jqGrid parameter to obtain the index of the row by given row id.

```
var grid = $("#jqGrid")[0];
var rowid = "somerowid";
var rowIndex = grid.p._index[rowid];

var datarow = grid.p.data[rowIndex];
```

The method  getLocaRow use similar approach.

In case the data is not local you can use **getInd** method

The methods here are used in Guriddo jqGrid. More on the methods can be found [Guriddo Documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#method-list)