# jqGrid addRowData does not fire afterInsertRow

Tags: free-jqgrid

I'm upgrading my jqGrid from 4.7.1 to 4.14

This is my script for initializing the grid

```
jQuery("#detFlex62_1").jqGrid({
    url: root + mod + '/detaillistview',
    datatype: "local",
    colNames:[' ', '<?=lang("users_company_code")?>', '<?=lang("users_company_name")?>', ' ', ' '],
    colModel:[
        {name:'myac', width:50, fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false, formatter:'actions', formatoptions:{keys:true, editbutton : false, delbutton : false, delOptions: {reloadAfterSubmit:false},editOptions: {reloadAfterSubmit:false}}},
        {name:'company_code',index:'company_code', width:100},
        {name:'company_name',index:'company_name', width:100},
        {name:'company_id',index:'company_id', width:100,hidden:true},
        {name:'company_access_id',index:'company_access_id', width:100,hidden:true}
        ],
    width: $('.body').width()-40,
    height: 120,
    pager: '#pagerFlex62_1',
    sortname: 'user_id',
    sortorder: "desc",
    editurl: root + mod + '/detailpost',
    caption:"<?=lang("users_title")?>",
    onSelectRow: function(id){
        activedf = "#detFlex62_1";
    },
    afterInsertRow: function (rowid) {
        var grid = $(this),
        iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid,'myac'); // 'act' - name of the actions column
        grid.find(">tbody>tr[id=" + rowid + "].jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")")
        .each(function() {
            $("<div>",
                {
                    title: "Edit",
                    mouseover: function() {
                        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                    },
                    mouseout: function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                    },
                    click: function(e) {
                      df_edit_1($(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"));
                        /*alert("'Custom' button is clicked in the rowis="+
                              $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id") +" !");*/
                    }
                }
              ).css({float:"left"})
               .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-edit")
               .append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>')
               .prependTo($(this).children("div"));

            $("<div>",
                {
                    title: "Delete",
                    mouseover: function() {
                        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                    },
                    mouseout: function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                    },
                    click: function(e) {
                      df_delete_1($(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"));
                        /*alert("'Custom' button is clicked in the rowis="+
                              $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id") +" !");*/
                    }
                }
              ).css({float:"left"})
               .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-edit")
               .append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span>')
               .prependTo($(this).children("div"));

        });
    }
});

jQuery("#detFlex62_1").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerFlex62_1',{edit:false,del:false,search:false, addfunc: df_add_1, editfunc: df_edit_1});
```

And here is where I add new row into the grid

```
function df_addToJSON_1(form)
{
    var idx = $('input[name=index]',form).val();
    var id = $('input[name=id]',form).val();

    var totalRows = jQuery("#detFlex62_1").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
    var data = {
        company_code: $('input[name=company_code]',form).val(),
        company_name: $('input[name=company_name]',form).val(),
        company_id: $('input[name=company_id]',form).val(),
        company_access_id: $('input[name=company_access_id]',form).val()
    };

    if (idx=='')
    {
        idx = getMaxRowId($('#detFlex62_1'));
        $('#detFlex62_1').jqGrid("addRowData", idx + 1, data, "last");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#detFlex62_1').jqGrid("setRowData", idx, data);
    }

    //pCheckShow();
    return false;
}
```

The new row is added, but without triggering the afterInsertRow event. Why is this happening? Is there a mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Free jqGrid supports `afterAddRow`, `afterSetRow` and `afterDelRow` callbacks, which will be called at the end of `addRowData`, `setRowData` and `delRowData` methods. The most new callbacks introduced by free jqGrid has one parameter (`options`, for example), which properties contains additional information. It allows to use only the properties, which one need, without require to insert unneeded first parameters if you need to use only the last parameter of old-style callback. Additionally, the new-style of callback parameters allows easy to extend the options in the future release of free jqGrid.

Thus you can, for example, change `afterInsertRow: function (rowid) {` to `afterAddRow: function (options) { var rowid = options.rowid;`

In general I would recommend you to make more changes in your code. What you do inside of `afterInsertRow` is creating custom action button. Your code is long and slow because jqGrid 4.7 had no simple way to create custom action button. Free jqGrid do supports the feature. I recommend you to read [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Enhancement-of-formatter:%22actions%22), to examine the code of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/CustomActionButton.htm), [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/CustomActionButton1.htm) and the demos included in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42222717/315935). You will see that creating action buttons is very easy. You will have full control over `onClick` callback.

Comment: It is an honor to be answered by you. I tried your first suggestion, changing the afterInsertRow to afterAddRow. It doesn't work. I will read the enhanced formatter actions later. I agree the code is slow, I will apply the enhanced formatter actions in the near future. But seeing the event afterAddRow / afterInsertRow is not fired just weird for me. (tried both)

Comment: @strike_noir: Everything will be more easy if you provide **the demo**. I get the first demo described in [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) and modified to test `afterAddRow` callback. You can see on https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/r4xo7ncr/ that the callback do called.